# Help please I have task Web application for efficient placement of blocks

Tags: 2d, javascript, json, html, css

Task: to develop a function that efficiently places rectangular blocks in
rectangular 2D container. The location of the blocks in the container should be
as dense as possible in order to rationally use the space of the container.

I almsot done but I have some problem with my code items
overlap each other

here is my code but I dont want use some libriries

Block Placement Algorithm
  
    .container {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    .block {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
  


  
  
 function checkOverlap(newBlock, existingBlocks) {
  for (const block of existingBlocks) {
    if (
      newBlock.right >= block.left - blockMargin &&
      newBlock.left = block.top - blockMargin &&
      newBlock.top  a.initialOrder - b.initialOrder);

    // Render blocks on the page
    const container = document.getElementById('container');

    let currentTop = 0;
    let currentLeft = 0;

    blockCoordinates.forEach(block => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'block';
      div.style.width = block.width + 'px';
      div.style.height = block.height + 'px';

      // Set position based on the order with margin
      div.style.top = currentTop + 'px';
      div.style.left = currentLeft + 'px';
      div.textContent = block.initialOrder;

      const randomColor = "#" + ((1  containerWidth) {
        currentTop += block.height + blockMargin; 
        currentLeft = 0; 
      }
    });

Comment: Please post each question only once. Use the "edit" link at the bottom if you want to make corrections after posting.